# Difference between 而, 但 and 和

Tags: word-choice

和 means 'and', and so does 而. What is the difference between the two. I also know that 而 means 'but', and the second question is what is the difference between 而 and 但. Give me an example sentence, please.

Comment: 但 is a "stronger" but, 而 is a "weaker" but. Besides, 而且 means `besides / furthermore / (not only ...) but also`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use 而, you are always expressing some kind of adversative meaning weaker than 但. Most of the time they can substitute each other but not 100% certain.

Example 1:  both are fine

> *这件事很难，而那件事很容易。 => This thing is difficult while that one is easy.*
>   *这件事很难，但那件事很容易。 => This thing is difficult but that one is easy.*

Example 2: 而 is better here

> *他没有出国，而是留在了国内。 => He stayed in home country instead of going abroad.*

Example 3: 但 is better

> *这杯水不甜，但富含营养。 => This cup of water is not sweet but full of nutrition.*

The differencies are subtle, taste them in more practice.

---

It's clearer to distinguish 而 from 和. Remember 和 has no adversative meaning, and in most cases it connects objects:

> *Tom and Jerry are good friends.*
>   Correct: *汤姆和杰瑞是好朋友。*
>   Wrong: *汤姆而杰瑞是好朋友。*

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding is:

```
 and<->和
 while<->而
 but<->但
```

when they are used as conjunction. One want to give a comparison when he use 而.

Answer (score 0):

和 and 而 can be substituted occasionally when 而 connects two adjectives or verbs, but it is not very natural. I'd think it is similar to the words "and" in English, or other European language. Some examples:

她堅強而果斷的態度十分吸引人=》她堅強和果斷的態度十分吸引人。

他們堅持和推進了問題的解決=》他們堅持而（而且）推進了問題的解決

Comment: Can you tidy up your answer a bit? Get rid of the random punctuations; correct the misspellings and grammar; expand on your answer a bit more.