# What's the difference between 也 (yě) & 和 （hé)?

Tags: translation, nuance

[Difference between 而, 但 and 和](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/3456/difference-between-%E8%80%8C-%E4%BD%86-and-%E5%92%8C) contrasts 和 with two others, but doesn't mention 也.

"And" vs. "also" … ?

Comment: 也：adverb/副词，和：preposition／介词, conjunction／连词

Answer (score 2, accepted):

也 means "also" whereas 和 means "and."  Adverb vs. conjunction.

So for example, to say "I am also a student" you could write

```
我也是学生。
```

But you cannot write

```
我和是学生。
```

Additionally, 也 cannot function as 和。To say "My friend and I are watching a movie" you could write

```
我和我的朋友在看电影。
```

But you cannot write

```
我也我的朋友在看电影。
```

Here are some links you might want to check out (both on ChineseGrammarWiki):

- [The "also" adverb "ye"](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/The_%22also%22_adverb_%22ye%22)
- [Expressing "and" with "he"](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22and%22_with_%22he%22)

Comment: So one ties an event/action/equation to a previous one, and the other puts nouns in pairs/groups.  Thanks.

Comment: users note that answer was edited 1 hour ago to include the terms adverb and conjunction (和 also functions as preposition) suggested by comment 4 hrs ago

Answer (score 0):

I think 和 is more complicated than just 'and'. It shows a mouth 口 and 禾 a plant like rice. Its original meaning may have been something like 'in time of peace we have food to eat'. Its sense of 'and' may have evolved from 'peace - together - with - and'

If you look here you can see a lot of meanings: http://www.iciba.com/%E5%92%8C
I think sometimes 和 and 跟 are interchangeable.

I hear '我也要‘ a lot 'I want some too'

I read 也 may be a picture of a wash basin, but I'm not convinced of that. Anyone have better info?

Comment: If the pages ccless1 cited are correct, they are not interchangeable.  I do not know how to interpret icier, but I find it hard to believe all those entries are meanings of 和

Comment: Have a look here then, oh ye of little faith! http://www.zdic.net/z/16/js/548C.htm

Comment: I don't know how to interpret that either, and if I try to get a hint from Google Translate, it tells me either of those URIs translate to a completely blank page :-).  My suspicion was that they showed examples of usage or meanings of combinations as opposed to the character as a one-syllable word.  Are you saying the "Grammar Wiki" is wrong?  (Being a Wiki, it certainly could be!)

Comment: I think it's like this: when you read Chinese, you will come across a 1 character word and you think,"What's that doing there?" So you ask someone and they say, "Oh, that means XX" a 2 character word. If you are Chinese, you know what is meant, so a lot of times bits are left out. Makes hard reading for us 外国！ Does 和 or 和平 mean peace? Depends on who is writing! People who eat together are probably at peace with each other.